# How to protect scripts directory

Tags: php, permissions

My php script dir is totally accessible via the browser via http://mydomain.com/scripts/

What permissions do I need to set it to so that a) there isn't public access and b) outside clients like PayPal IPN still have access?

Comment: what do you mean, "totally accessible"? You can browse that dir? Turn off browsing, then. Make the url path be totally unguessable. If it's not for public consumption, then make the subdir(s) `/q2342345rwedfasdertasdfzsdfzsdf/asdf/asdf/asdf/asdf/`. Paypal won't care how ugly the path is.

Comment: Yes, there is a directory tree listing

Comment: The user can easily see the directory path in the Ajax calls in the Jquery. Making it unguessable won't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want that your files/folders under scripts directory are not visible when someone hits http://mydomain.com/scripts/ then you can simple put up an index.html file in scripts/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions so nothing is writable

Add a .htaccess file to scripts/ on your site that simply says

```
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add file `index.html` to that directory to avoid others to see the files..

Comment: Can you please explain the OP why does this help?

Comment: u have a directory called scripts and u want to hide files in that directory right..?????

Comment: I know what he wants and that your solution works. But the solution is not obvious to someone who does not know how Apache (or other web servers) works.